# How to view the text in an NSString in debug

Tags: xcode, debugging

I'm new to XCode 4 and I cannot figure out how to view the value of a variable such as a NSCFString while in a breakpoint.  I see my Autos/Local but they are showing Hex values with Summary Unavailable.  All I want to do is see the string itself as regular text.  I'm even hovering over variables expecting to see their values like in Visual Studio with no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turn on console view for debugger and at the prompt type:

```
(lldb) po myStringVariable
```

or

```
(lldb) po [self someStringProperty]
```